# How to remove sprite after the completion on Animation?

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-android

I am using the CCAnimation class for using animation with more than one CCSprite . What I want is :

" **Just Remove the sprite after the animation complete** "

If anybody work on this, Please Let me Know. What should  I do for it.

Comment: If  I have only a sprite than I can apply the removeChid method for it but in the case of animation I not apply this one on it ... So , what method I use for it ?

Answer (score 5):

I know the solution of [pktangyue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1076889/pktangyue) works but I want to add a new answer because this is deprecated in ***cocos2d-x V3.x***   Please read the final way to do this it's more easy

```
Node *nodeSprite =(Node*)layer->getChildByName("BFL_Ready_Label");
MoveTo* animation = MoveTo::create(1.0f,Point(Director::getInstance()->getWinSize().width/2,Director::getInstance()->getWinSize().height*1.5));
CallFunc* animationDone = CallFunc::create(bind(&Node::removeFromParent,nodeSprite));
Sequence* sequence = Sequence::create(animation,animation,NULL);
node->runAction(Sequence);
```

And like the previous answer using a Sprite.

```
MoveTo* animation = MoveTo::create(1.0f,Point(Director::getInstance()->getWinSize().width/2,Director::getInstance()->getWinSize().height*1.5));
CallFunc::create(bind(&Sprite::removeFromParent,m_sprite));
Sequence* sequence = Sequence::create(animation,animation,NULL);
m_sprite->runAction(sequence);
```

Using this the compiler will not tell that you're using deprecated methods. I hope this will useful.

I update this answer because there's a much easy way to do this
when you create a sequence just add the **RemoveSelf::create** RemoveSelf it's an action so you can add it to the sequence it will destroy the sprite or Node after the animation is complete.

```
Sequence* sequence = Sequence::create(animation,animation,RemoveSelf::Create(),NULL);
```

And that's the easy way to destroy the object after 
the animation is completed this is very usefull in particles

Answer (score 3):

Suppose `m_action` is your animation and `m_sprite` is you sprite node.

Then you can create a `CCSequence` action, with a `CCCallFunc` action in the final, like the following code:

```
CCSequence* seq = CCSequence::create(action,
                                     CCCallFunc::create(m_sprite, callfunc_selector(CCSprite::removeFromParent),
                                     NULL);
m_sprite->runAction(seq);
```

Answer (score 0):

sprite_name->runAction(Sequence::create(ScaleTo::create(1, 0),RemoveSelf::create(), NULL));

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).